# jQuery - get array with input names as keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need get the same type of array that `this.form.elements` returns, with input names as array keys.

I tried `this.toArray()`, but even though it looks the same, it's missing the name keys (the keys are numbers).

Here's the full function:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.blah = function(){
    var that = this;
    return this.each(function(){
       $(this).bind('change', function(){
           var matches1 = that.toArray();  // this doesn't work
           var matches2 = this.form.elements;  // this works.

           console.log(matches1); // but both arrays look the same. wtf?
           console.log(matches2);

           return true;
        }).change();

   });
 };

 })(jQuery);
```

using it as `$("input").blah();`

Comment: that depends on what is the value of `this`.

Comment: it's a set of selectors, comes from `$("input").somefunction()....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript you don't use an Array for named keys. You'd use an Object instead. I assume the values should be the elements themselves.

```
var result = {};

$.each(this.form.elements, function() {
    result[ this.name ] = this;
});
```

---

<s>Regarding your update, this line:</s>

```
var matches1 = that.toArray();
```

...doesn't work because you're calling jQuery's `toArray()` against a jQuery object.

If you wanted to use that, you'd call it from the library, and pass it the jQuery object.

```
var matches1 = $.toArray( that );
```

...although I don't know why you'd want to turn the jQuery object representing all `<input>` element  into an Array  on each `change` event.

This line:

```
var matches2 = this.form.elements;  // this works.
```

... works because it is simply a reference to the elements in the form from the `<input>` element that received the event. It uses native DOM API properties to get a collection (that isn't technically an Array).

---

Had to edit my answer because I was wrong about the use of `toArray()`. I was thinking of `makeArray()`. The `toArray()` method is a wrapper for `.get()` and does exactly the same thing.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation :) So can I get a reference to the elements from "that" just like ".elements" does from "this.form" ?

Comment: @Alexandra: Your `that` variable is a reference to a jQuery object that contains the result of your original `$('input')` selection. As such, it references *all* inputs that were found on the page. When you do `this.form.elements`, you're only referencing the elements in the same form as `this` (which is the element that received the `change` event).

Comment: I think your last comment pretty much wraps this up.

Comment: @karim79: Could be. I've got to admit that I can't quite figure out the ultimate intent of the code yet.

Comment: @karim79: Though I was completely wrong about `toArray`. It's just a wrapper for `.get()`. I was thinking of `makeArray`. Sometimes I just have to roll my eyes at parts of this API.

Answer (score 2):

Serialize is a possible choice.
http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

$(this).serializeArray() rertuns it. :)

Answer (score 1):

`form.elements` returns an object of [`HTMLCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506) or [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlformcontrolscollection) in HTML5.

The elements in these objects are accessible by index or name. So if you have a form with a single input element named "login", you could do:

```
form.elements.[0]
```

or

```
form.elements["login"]
```

to access the same element. You could simulate such an object by adding two entries for each form element with its corresponding index and name. But if `form.elements` works for you, I'd recommend using that directly.